# A faster route to deploying static content in Magento 2? Dev to Live etc?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, git, static-content, deployment

Massive bounty on this guys. Wanted to get some attention here. Maybe move it here instead..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589283/a-faster-route-to-deploying-static-content-in-magento-2-dev-to-live-etc

Can no one answer ?

Comment: Can you move this question to here?